# Using Pivot Tables to track user chat log

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, group-by, pivot-table

I have a platform tracking multiple customer and rep chats. I want to create data frames containing a single customer's entire, ordered chat history.

Here's [a link to the example data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ClGy0kgqblfUOQOC6jRGSYr6y-YiNTnVmifAu6nVh6o/edit?usp=sharing)

And for quick reference:

```
Convo Room      Date        Message Order       User ID     Role        Chat contents
A1      3-Oct-17        1       JOHN        CUSTOMER        Hi, can you help?
A1      4-Oct-17        2       ALICE       REP     Sure, what's up?
A1      5-Oct-17        3       JOHN        CUSTOMER        I have warts.
A1      6-Oct-17        4       JOHN        CUSTOMER        Please don't hang up, it's just warts.
B1      7-Oct-17        1       JOHN        CUSTOMER        Hi, can YOU help?
B1      8-Oct-17        2       MARY        REP     Sure, I heard about Alice.
B1      9-Oct-17        3       MARY        REP     I also have warts.
B1      10-Oct-17       4       JOHN        CUSTOMER        Oh, nevermind then, gotta go.
C1      7-Oct-17        1       JIM     CUSTOMER        Hi, can you help?
C1      8-Oct-17        2       ALICE       REP     Maybe, what's up?
C1      9-Oct-17        3       JIM     CUSTOMER        Not warts.
C1      10-Oct-17       4       ALICE       REP     Good, that's the only thing I cannot handle.
D1      15-Oct-17       1       JOHN        CUSTOMER        Hi, pls help. Warts.
D1      16-Oct-17       2       JUDE        REP     Perfect, I cure them!
D1      17-Oct-17       3       JUDE        REP     …with fire.
D1      18-Oct-17       4       JUDE        REP     Are you still there? Dang, lost another one.
```

In my mind, the first step is to get the data ordered using pivot tables. Next, I can focus on separating chats into data frames for sentiment analysis or other metrics.

I believe I am close, but I keep getting one part of the sorting wrong.

What I have so far:

```
df = test.pivot_table(index=['Role', 'User ID', 'Date', 'Convo Room', 'Message Order'],columns=["Role"],aggfunc='first')
df.head()
```

Which returns the following:
[image: almost but no cigar]
Using Excel, I believe this is generally what I want though I'm certain there are many ways to visualize this:

[image: the goal]

Answer (score 0):

You are in the right track , just need to make sure you pass the right column into `pivot_table`

```
df.pivot_table(index=[ 'User ID', 'Convo Room', 'Message Order'],columns=["Role"],values='Chat contents',aggfunc='first')
```

Comment: almost, but that doesn't quite do it either. The User ID's are sorted, but I still cannot seem to get the messages to go back-and-forth internal to the User ID. I'm not sure there is a way to re-reference the same User ID internal to the pivot table once previously referenced!